# $(a,this).attr('href') returns undefined

Tags: jquery, mysql, hyperlink, href, undefined

Im using ajax to load some data from a mysql database... my problem is, it getting the id for the data i want to load, i have set the HREF value as the id... so an example is:

```
`<a href="16" title="View Story: ssasds">ssasds</a>`,
```

16 is the id value i need... my code is:

```
$('.artefact').click(function()
                {

                var storyId = $('a',this).attr('href');
                console.log(storyId);
                               }
```

when i check the console (firebug) it just says undefined. please try and help out, as i have tried other methods of getting the data but gets messy.

thanks

Comment: try `console.log($("a", this))` and also try `$(this).find("a")`

Comment: may be you need to use just $(this).attr('href')

Comment: <div class="story_preview">
            <div class="artefact"><a  title="View Story: ssasds"> <img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/VQ-nS9Q-prw/default.jpg" width="130" height="90" alt="ssasds video Preview"> </a>
            <div class="story_title"><a href="16" title="View Story: ssasds">ssasds</a></div>
            </div>

Comment: @Neil Stewart: You have to links (a), and first one doesn't have href attribute.
So to get that href, you could use: $('a', this).last().attr('href'). (I think this was correct syntax)

Comment: @Enoyhs that was the problem.. thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like `.artefact` has two `a`s. Based on this:

```
$('.artefact').click(function () {
    var storyId = $('a', this).filter("[href]").attr('href');
    console.log(storyId);
});
```

## EDIT

On second thought, this looks cleaner:

```
$('.artefact').click(function () {
    var storyId = $(this).find("a[href]").attr('href');
    console.log(storyId);
});
```

Comment: I am retard.... FIXED. i didnt realise that A) The link i did have in, was infact within a different DIV that was also in artefact, but B) that the first link in the artefact div, has no HREF attribute. Im sorry for wasting time :(

Comment: @Neil: You're not creating a YouTube playlist, are you?

Comment: No. i have a university coursework to make a web magazine type thing... i've decided to make a website that looks like a news paper, im using PHP and jquery to load the stories from a database... newspaper.nmyster.co.uk if you wanna check it out. im new to jquery.

Comment: I meant AJAX and PHP, but using Jquery cause its better

Answer (score 2):

Is `.artefact` a link? If yes, why to use `$('a', this)` instead of just `$(this)`?

Comment: .artefact is a div, it has an image in it and a anchor tag.

Comment: using @Raynos comment on your question (the `$(this).find('a')` part) should work with that combination

Comment: [a, a 16] is returned when i use ("a", this)) in the console, so how would i get the 17 on its own, can i just create a variable with ("a",this) as the value, then cut the string the last three chatacters, then remove the ]

Comment: Hmm... look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5vPhK/ - is it your case? It works just right.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 links in the div element (Looking at code you provided). So to get the href (if that link is always the last one in div, you should use:

```
$('.artefact').click(function() {
  var storyId = $('a', this).last().attr('href');
  console.log(storyId);
});
```

And as others have said, you were missing parentesis too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var storyId = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `$(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, closing parenthesis is in fault http://jsfiddle.net/h7HuJ/1/ I used your given HTML code.

You have two anchors inside that DIV, so you need to specify, which one to select. I used your class name.

Answer (score 0):

@Neil Stewart: See -- http://jsfiddle.net/Chby2/

You didn't add the `artefact` class to the link and your jQuery code was also missing the closing parenthesis: `);`

Comment: I tried the link, and it works... i tried to copy that into my script, and it does not... awww :(. I the artefact div, is held in a another div called story_preivew. and these are brought in using PHP when the page is loaded... would that have anything to do with the problem? I know if you get data using ajax you need to use .live() but i didnt think that would be a problem in this case